# OrientDB indexes are not working properly with formatted params used in server functions

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB is throwing a java.lang.ClassCastException when a sever function (a query on indexed fields) is executed with formatted params.
Following messages are seen with the exception.
"Error on using index", "Probably you need to rebuild indexes. Now executing query using cluster scan

e.g.

```
db.query("SELECT FROM Employee WHERE department = ?", departmentRid);
where, Employee.department is indexed with NOT_UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX
```

When I removed the formatted params and injected them manually index worked out fine. 
e.g.

```
db.query("SELECT FROM Employee WHERE department = " + departmentRid);
```

Any reason why the first approach didn't work? I'd like to refrain from injecting the params manually.

Note that the both approaches gives me the correct result. The problem is that the index is not applied for the first approach.

I am using orientdb-community-2.1.0

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have the stack trace?

Comment: Hi, I tried to reproduce your problem and it works.
Can you post the entire function ?

Comment: this is my entire function(javascript) ,

return db.query('SELECT FROM Employee WHERE department = ?', departmentRid);

departmentRid is a function argument

For this simple example i dont see any stacktrace, but this simple error message 
"Error on using index Employee.department in query 'SELECT FROM Employee WHERE department = ?'. Probably you need to rebuild indexes. Now executing query using cluster scan
java.lang.ClassCastException"

And yes, I did rebuild the index..

Comment: @Alessandro, did you try it out in 2.1.0 or a later version? In case you want to try out my exact scenario here are the details. My entities are Employee(name:String, department:Department) and Department(name). I have 2 departments i.e. HR and IT. And 2 employees called A and B. A in HR, B in IT. And have the NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX on department field of Employee.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with version 2.1.0, I have the NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX on department field of Employee and it works

[image]

Comment: It gives me the correct result too. The problem is that the index is not getting applied and on the console I see an exception has been thrown and has fallen back to cluster scan mode. Can you also confirm that you don't get any errors in the console and the index has been applied correctly? P.S. I just edited the question to clarify the same.

Comment: I can confirm that I got errors in the console and also the index has not been used.

Comment: Raised an Issue at github. https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5270